# Singularity of the python logic

Tags: python

Just starting to get to know Python. Every Python expression is supposed to have a boolean value. I'm trying to verify it with simple statements, the results are a bit confusing. In principle this does not seem to have an easy logic to understand. There is something behind it that is lost to me. What could it be?

```
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> foo = 1
> foo is True
False
> bar = True if foo else False
> print("{}".format(bar))
True
> 
> foo = 0
> foo is True
False
> bar = True if foo else False
> print("{}".format(bar))
False
```

```
> foo = '1'
> foo is True
False
> bar = True if foo else False
> print("{}".format(bar))
True
> 
> foo = '0'
> foo is True
False
> bar = True if foo else False
> print("{}".format(bar))
True
```

Comment: Don't use `is` here. Repeat the tests with `==`. `is` has a very particular use.

Comment: Yes...you're mixing up `True` and "truish".  Many statements are "truish" in Python, but `True` is a particular value that's harder to get.  You don't have to set a value to `True` to get it to have that value.  The result of a boolean expression is one of the values `True` or `False`. `foo = 3; bar = foo == 3` results in `bar` being the value `True`.

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html.  Note the use of lowercase "true" vs uppercase "True".  The former, as discussed here, is what I called "truish" in my prior comment.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `is` is not the same as `==`, since is is asking if it is exactly that value/object. To check if something is 'truthy' or 'falsey' (since they cannot actually be the boolean values of True or False), you can do for example:

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> True if foo else False
True
>>> foo = 0
>>> True if foo else False
False

>>> bar = '0'
>>> True if bar else False
True
>>> bar = ''
>>> True if bar else False
False
```

In general, empty lists, strings etc. and 0 are 'falsey' while most other things are 'truthy'. Maybe you would prefer the explanation here instead: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/